# Spring, RabbitMQ, Sleuth and Zipkin: No tracings available in Zipkin

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-sleuth, zipkin

Im trying to implement distributed tracing using Spring, RabbitMQ, Sleuth and Zipkin. So I added the dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-bus-amqp</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And configured `sleuth` and `zipkin` in my `bootstrap.yml`:

```
spring:
  sleuth:
    sampler:
      probability: 1.0
  zipkin:
    rabbitmq:
      addresses: ${RABBIT_MQ_HOST:localhost}:${RABBIT_MQ_PORT:5672}
    sender:
      type: rabbit
```

So starting my services and making some rest calls I get this in the logs:

```
zuul-gateway                    | 2020-04-01 01:49:25.453  INFO [zuul-gateway,384ce1318abef3f3,74ad64f70e120f4e,true] 1 --- [nio-8765-exec-4] d.f.z.ZuulLoggingFilter                               : request -> org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.pre.Servlet30RequestWrapper@70eb5e67 request uri -> /user-service/users
user-service-3                  | 2020-04-01 01:49:25.462  INFO [user-service,384ce1318abef3f3,4522ae801a21c30e,true] 1 --- [nio-8000-exec-2] de.fronetic.userservice.UserController                : Order by: age, Users: [User(id=4, lastName=Savona, firstName=Albert, age=101), User(id=3, lastName=Esposito, firstName=Derryl, age=12), User(id=1, lastName=Belmonte, firstName=Maeleth, age=14), User(id=6, lastName=Grillo, firstName=Madhu, age=21), User(id=2, lastName=Colt, firstName=Tychon, age=28), User(id=8, lastName=Causer, firstName=Stana, age=44), User(id=7, lastName=Seelen, firstName=Bellatrix, age=52), User(id=5, lastName=Hakobyan, firstName=Zinoviy, age=57)]
user-transformation-service     | 2020-04-01 01:49:25.475  INFO [user-transformation-service,384ce1318abef3f3,47a61185e3cca375,true] 1 --- [nio-8100-exec-7] d.f.u.UserTransformationController     : Users: [User(id=4, lastName=Savona, firstName=Albert, age=101), User(id=3, lastName=Esposito, firstName=Derryl, age=12), User(id=1, lastName=Belmonte, firstName=Maeleth, age=14), User(id=6, lastName=Grillo, firstName=Madhu, age=21), User(id=2, lastName=Colt, firstName=Tychon, age=28), User(id=8, lastName=Causer, firstName=Stana, age=44), User(id=7, lastName=Seelen, firstName=Bellatrix, age=52), User(id=5, lastName=Hakobyan, firstName=Zinoviy, age=57)]
```

For now it looks good. Sleuth added the tracing ID's.
Calling the Zipkin UI I can see that the service names where added:

[image]

But there are no tracing informations at all:

[image]

So im wondering what im missing in my configuration.

**EDIT**

Turned out there are tracing informations arriving in zipkin. I can use the search bar in the top right corner to search for tracing id's directly:

[image]

I will then get:

[image]

So the question is why is there nothing in the overview or queryable via the trace lookup?

Comment: Just use a release train. Otherwise I have no guarantee that you don't have classpath issues

Comment: Ok, thx. Using the Hoxton.SR3 now. Problem remains the same.

Comment: Currently figuring something out. Zipkin actually does receive tracing informations. I can search for tracing ID's in Zipkin and it finds the traces. Only the zipkin overview and search bar give me no results at all.